# Передача координат персонажа из одного класса в другой в Unity

Tags: unity3d

При написании своего "проекта" столкнулся с проблемой передачи координат персонажа из одного класса в другой. Суть в чем. У меня есть персонаж, у него есть скрипт движения, и есть враг со своим скриптом, где описан его банальный ИИ. Как можно сделать так, чтобы мировые координаты персонажа можно было передать в скрипт с ИИ врага? Движение игрока в методе Update, получить эти координаты можно банально через transform, но передать их так просто не получается. Создавал дополнительный метод в скрипте игрока для последующего его вызова в скрипте врага, но максимум получилось передать локальные координаты. А вообще это всё мне нужно для того, чтобы враг знал местоположение персонажа. 
Есть какие-то идеи? Буду признателен любым подсказкам. Спасибо.

Comment: храните ссылку на трансформ игрока и берите его позицию

Answer (score 0):

Где то в Старте класса Врага найдите игрока через `FindObjectOfType<SomePlayerScript>()`

```
Transform playerTransform = FindObjectOfType<SomePlayerScript>()?.transform
```

И дальше уже творите с ним все что захотите. Если там, конечно, не `null` 
Глобальную позицию (`playerTransform.position`), локальную позицию (`playerTransform.localPosition`)

Comment: Спасибо большое, выручили. Всё заработало

Answer (score 0):

Вот 2 способа (3 описан в другом ответе): 
1) Создаем у врага поле

```
[SerializeField] private Transform _targetPlayer;
```

В инспекторе перетаскиваем персонажа на это поле и используем координаты _targetPlayer для ИИ как цель.
2) У Игрока создаем публичный метод:

```
public Vector3 GetPlayerTransform()
{
   return transform.position;
}
```

далее у врага создаем объект класса и получаем из player'a координаты:

```
var player = new Player();
Vector3 target = player.GetPlayerTransform();
```

и у вас в target записаны координаты игрока. Удачи

Answer (score 0):

Я просто прописал в классе объекта который ты хочешь отследить

public Transform targetplayer;

В инспекторе этого объекта в скрипте будет Transform targetplayer и в его поле назначаешь объект после чего будешь targetplayer это массив с данными transfor, где можно взять Transform.position x,y,z что тебе нужно

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно получить позицию одного объекта в скрипте другого:

```
Transform pos = FindObjectOfType<NewBehaviourScript>()?.transform;
txt.text = "x: " + pos.position.x + "y: " + pos.position.y+ "z: " + pos.position.z.ToString();
```